# Comparar valores de array com variável

Tags: php

Tenho a necessidade de somar valores vindo de um array e comparar com um valor vindo de uma variável.

Ex:

```
array(1000, 1000, 3000, 5000,);

$var = 4000;
```

No caso deve-se somar dentro do array 1000+3000, então se achará o 4000. As posições do array será aleatoria, a soma pode ser entre 2,3,4,.. valores.

E possível somente com php?

Comment: Pode explicar um pouco melhor o que você precisa? Mostre um exemplo prático, com o array, o valor e o resultado esperado.

Comment: deu um duplo sentido pois a primeira vista parece que é apenas somar tudo e comparar.. isso é bem fácil. Mas parece que pede para que obtenha a soma que seja igual ao valor da variável.. aí já é outra conversa.. Descreva melhor o que realmente precisa.

Comment: Então no caso, preciso achar o valor de uma variável dentro do array com diversos valores, então fazer todas as somas possíveis desse array e verificar se e igual a variável.

Comment: Coloca um exemplo na pergunta, pelo menos com o que tem até agora parece que vc quer apenas comparar o 4000 com o 1000(2x), 3000 e 5000. Essa parte da soma não ficou clara.

Comment: @William, então está faltando algo porque se encontar o valor 4 mil dentro do array, obviamente que após isso, a soma de todos os outros nunca vai dar igual ao 4 mil. A não ser que exista outro valor para comparar ou que todos os outros sejam zero. Está confuso. Se quer buscar o valor específico dentro do array, é conforme o rray postou. Mas depois disso está confuso a sua explicação sobre o que seria essa soma.

Comment: @DanielOmine editei a pergunta

Comment: está mais claro.. Nesse caso tem que fazer permutação dos dados do array e ir somando..  Essa pegunta pode te dar um esclarecimento sobre a permutação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126783/permuta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-array  Mas sobre a soma, necessita de uma implementação específica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que isso pode te ajudar. Achei aqui no [Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34644/encontrar-somat%C3%B3ria-de-valores-em-array).

```
   $values  = array(1000, 1000, 3000, 5000);
   $expected = 4000;

   $len = count( $values );
   for( $i = 1; $i < pow( 2, $len ); $i++ ) {
      $soma = 0;
      $set = array();
      for( $j = 0; $j < $len; $j++ ) {
         if( 1 << $j & $i ) {
            $set[] = $j;
            $soma += $values[$j];
         }
      }
      if( $soma == $expected ) {
         // Estamos exibindo na tela apenas como demonstração.
         foreach( $set as $pos ) echo "[$pos]{$values[$pos]} ";
         echo " = $expected<br>\n";
      }
   }
```

Comment: Vou fazer alguns testes, algumas coisas ai não entendi no código.

Comment: Nossa que interessante, tentei com todas a possibilidades e ele não erra uma combinação. Muito bom. Vou tentar implementar no meu sistema de conciliação bancaria. Obrigado. E bem isso mesmo. Parabéns irmão.